# error generating qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am still learning R. Tried looking up the reason for this error but not quite sure.

**I am getting this error:**

[image]

**This is the .RMD code:**

[image]

All I did was try to plot a simple graph, where sp is the dataset.

The dataset lookis like this:

```
xAxis|count|yAxis  

18   |2    |0.1  
20   |2    |0.1  
22   |4    |0.3  
25   |2    |0.2  
30   |1    |0.1  
39   |2    |0.1
```

**UPDATE**
I tried saving the data like this:

```
SaveRDS(sp,file="C:\\Desktop\\sp1.RData")
```

I then wrote this code in R-Markdown:

```
library(datasets)  
load(file="C:\\Desktop\\sp1.RData")  
plot(sp$xAxis,sp$yAxis)
```

And got this Error:

[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where does the dataset 'sp' come from?  if it is yours, can you dput() it into the question?

Comment: @lawyeR yes, 'sp' is my dataset. I got it from sql like this..sp<-sqlQuery(sqlconnectionname,"Select query"). The data in it is decimals(y frequency) and int(x)

Comment: My point was that you need to give us some of the data so we can run your code and suggest what to do.  Or make up mock data.

Comment: have you loaded `sp` into the r-markdown environment? from your code snippet (btw, better to post actual code and not image) it looks like you haven't

Comment: @lawyeR my bad. I have added mock data as requested. I tried saving the data and then loading it in R-markdown but still no joy. There is not much code honestly just plot(x,y). I just wanted to make sure I atleast see the chart once knitted

Comment: @bouncyball I have updated the question with actual code I ran and the new error I am getting

Comment: In the screenshot you’re showing, `sp` is **not defined**. You probably defined in your console rather than the R Notebook, then ran just a snippet from your notebook, and that works. But when you’re compiling your notebook, this happens in a clean session. Thus no `sp` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it. Thanks to all of you for guiding me in the right direction.
I first saved the file like this:

```
save(sp,file="C:\\Desktop\\sp.RData")
```

Then in R-Markdown, wrote something like this:

````
```{r load sp}
load("C:\\Desktop\\sp.RData")
plot(sp$xAxis,sp$yAxis)
```
````

Then pressed Knit to see the chart in the html popup window.